# How to hook four strain gauges (5 wire) to an ESP32?

Tags: esp8266, load-cell, strain-gage

I have four strain gauges (50 kg) with 5 wires each (red, black, white, green, and yellow) and I want to measure the weight of a platform. I assume those should be hooked to an HX711 load cell amplifier and ESP32 MCU if possible.

I see two problems there:

1. The strain gauge has a recommended excitation voltage 10-15 V which is not compatible with the HX711 or ESP32
2. I assume I need to hook them up to a Wheatstone bridge, but a single strain gauge is already a Wheatstone bridge. I can't figure out what should be the wiring scheme.

[I purchased strain gauges in Aliexpress](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1PCSX-pressure-sensor-S-load-cell-electronic-scale-sensor-Weighing-Sensor-20KG-30KG-50KG-100KG-200KG/32343937511.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.27424c4d29q3fI)

Answer (score 1):

These loadcells already have a wheatstone bridge in it, you only need to wire it up correctly. According to the homepage the wiring is as follows:
Red:power + 
Black:power -
Green:signal +
White: signal - 
Maybe the 5th wire isn't used or not important for you.

The exication voltage shouldn't be a problem. Just put the supply voltage of the HX711 to power+ and power-. The signal+ goes to in+ and signal- to in- of your HX711 module.
According to its datasheet the HX711 has a serial protocol so you can wire it up ti the SDIO interface of your ESP32.
This [datasheet](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/ForceFlex/hx711_english.pdf) has an example C-driver in it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question is:

1. like Dennis Ernst wrote excitation voltage isn't a problem. Seem to work fine when powered from HX711
2. You need to wire all 4 S type strain gauges in parallel and hook them to HX711.

No need for additional strain gauge power. Yellow wire in my case is strain gauge shield

Proved to be working.

[IoT Industrial Scale article on Sparkfun site](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/iot-industrial-scale/all)